# Как найти последовательность в бинарном файле? WinAPI/Win32

Tags: c, файлы, winapi

Как реализовать алгоритм поиска последовательности в бинарном файле, например 0001?

Файл открывается для чтения и идентифицируется его размер. Параметры (имя процесса и название файла) передаются через командную строку.

Код:

```
int blockchain(wchar_t *box){
 int i=0;
 DWORD dwCounter=0;
 BYTE buffer[BUFFERSIZE]={0};
 HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(box, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
     OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
 if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) 
 {
     wprintf(L"Error! Wrong file name!\n");
     return -5;
 }

 if(FALSE==ReadFile(hFile, &buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &dwCounter, NULL))
 {
 wprintf(L"Terminal failure: Unable to read from file.\n");
 CloseHandle(hFile);
 return -5;
 }
 else
 {
 for(i;i<dwCounter;i++)
 {
     SetFilePointer(hFile, -i, NULL, FILE_END);

 }
 if (memcmp(buffer + i, "asd", min((dwCounter - i), 4) == 0))
     wprintf(L"The data is found");
 else
     wprintf(L"The requested combination is unavailable\n");
 wprintf(L"\nData read from %s (%d bytes): \n", box, dwCounter);    
 }
 CloseHandle(hFile);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот код какой-то есть... Он работает?

Comment: Проблема есть. Я понял как работает функция memcmp и почему она возвращает единицу, то есть ложное нахождение комбинации в файле. Как только реализовать поиск этой комбинации в бинарном файле?

Comment: Ничего не понял в последней сентенции. Если использовать memcmp, то, видимо, надо пройти по всему файлу, остановившись, если получили 0.

Comment: @MBo Необходимо найти комбинацию 0001 в бинарном файле. Если ее нет, то вывести ошибку. А у меня функция не работает.

Comment: Для того, чтобы работала, нужно продумать логику. Читать файл в буфер целиком и ли кусками, и по буферу  - по всем буферу - пройти memcmp, смещая адрес.

Comment: @MBo Как реализовать блочное чтение?

Comment: Сначала нужно научиться читать всё в один буфер и обрабатывать - с блочным чтением есть свои тонкости.

Comment: @MBo Хорошо, я считал все в буфер с помощью ReadFile функции. При отладке программы я вижу, что в буфере. Вопрос. Как теперь написать, чтобы обнаруживалась эта комбинация?

Comment: Написать цикл, на каждом обороте которого memcmp использует следующий адрес из буфера

Comment: @MBo вот он for(i;i<dwCounter;i++)
 {
     SetFilePointer(hFile, -i, NULL, FILE_END);

 }
 if (memcmp(buffer + i, "asd", min((dwCounter - i), 4) == 0))
     wprintf(L"The data is found");

Comment: Здесь нет чтения. Почему бы не воспользоваться более высокоуровневыми функциями для работы с файлом?

Comment: @MBo Потому что WinAPI/Win32 осваиваю.